# Invoke Mbean via client program

Tags: java, mbeans

I created an mbean. Below is my configuration. I could see my bean configuration after the server startup on JMX console. I tried to stop/start the mbean from the jmx console and it is working.

But when I am writing the code to invoke the mbean via program running in the same JVM, I could not see my bean

mbean details : xyz.abc.test:service=myTestService,name=myTestServiceName

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
try {
    Set<ObjectName> names = new TreeSet<ObjectName>(server.queryNames(null, null));
    for (ObjectName name : names) {
        System.out.println("\tObjectName = " + name);
    }
```

The above code is not printing my bean to invoke. Even client program is not working.

```
url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8080/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```